# Linking posted jobs with company pages on StackOverflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

On StackOverflow Careers I posted a job but it is not linked to our StackOverflow Careers Company Page... How can I link these two?

Answer (score 1):

That happens in an out of band process that runs about every 10 minutes.  Can you check again and see if it is there now?  I see one job on the job board, and that job is showing up on the company page for me now.